# Jquery Validation Plugin - For numeric field only in certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make a validation with jQuery Validate for a numeric value but only when a radio button is checked; if the radio button isn't checked the field will be required but the user is able to insert alphanumeric values; the problem is that only verifies if the field is empty or not, and the console.log displays the values that I want (true or false), but when submit the data is sent to the server. This is what I have:

```
$("#new_redeem_coupon").validate({
    rules:{
        'redeem_coupon[confirmation_number]': {
            required: function(element){
                var v = $("#redeem_coupon_confirmation_number").attr("value");
                if($("#redeem_coupon_coupon_kind_0").attr("checked") == "checked"){
                    ret = (v == "");
                    console.log("VALUE1: " + ret);
                    return ret;
                }
                else{
                    var ret = (v == "" || isNaN(v));
                    console.log("VALUE2: " + ret);
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    errorPlacement:function(error, element){
        $(element).attr("title",error.html()).tooltip({track:true});
    },
    success:function(label){
    },
    errorClass: "invalid",
    focusCleanUp: true
});
```

I've also tried with the following code but it didn't work; the value remains in false always:

```
'redeem_coupon[confirmation_number]': { required:true, number: $("#redeem_coupon_coupon_kind_0").attr("checked") != "checked" }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Pablo Martí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Use the `add` and `remove` methods listed on: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

The rules:

```
$("#new_redeem_coupon").validate({
    rules:{
        'redeem_coupon[confirmation_number]': {required: true}
    },
    errorPlacement:function(error, element){
        $(element).attr("title",error.html()).tooltip({track:true});
    },
    success:function(label){
    },
    errorClass: "invalid",
    focusCleanUp: true
});
```

And I add a event over the radios to add and remove the rules for each situation:

```
$(".coupon_kind_opt").change(function(){
    if($("#redeem_coupon_coupon_kind_0").attr("checked") == "checked"){
        $("#redeem_coupon_confirmation_number").rules("remove", "number");
    }
    else{
        $("#redeem_coupon_confirmation_number").rules("add", {
            number: true
        });
    }
})
```